# 301 redirect to a rewritten URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an old rewritten URL:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/([0-9]+)/subject/([0-9]+)$ conversation.php?recipientid=$1&subjectid=$2 [L]
```

And I am changing to a simpler structure by omitting a parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/([0-9]+)$ onversation.php?recipientid=$1 [L]
```

How do I 301 redirect my old URLs to the new format?

As I understand it I want to first do a 301 redirect from the old format to the new format, and then a second redirect to my PHP file.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your old rewrite rule and add:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/([0-9]+)/subject/([0-9]+)$ /messages/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**before** the new rule that you have:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/([0-9]+)$ conversation.php?recipientid=$1 [L]
```